# landscape tells me "network plugin raised an exception"

Tags: networking, landscape

On logging into my server I'm greeted with this message:

```
  => There were exceptions while processing one or more plugins. See
     /var/log/landscape/sysinfo.log for more information.
```

Here are the contents of `sysinfo.log`:

```
2021-11-23 02:50:34,701 ERROR    Network plugin raised an exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/sysinfo/sysinfo.py", line 99, in run
    result = plugin.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/sysinfo/network.py", line 36, in run
    device_info = self._get_device_info()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/lib/network.py", line 151, in get_active_device_info
    for interface, ifaddresses in get_active_interfaces():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/landscape/lib/network.py", line 58, in get_active_interfaces
    ifaddresses = netifaces.ifaddresses(interface)
ValueError: You must specify a valid interface name.
```

I've never heard of landscape before. What's broken here?

Comment: Same problem here - have you found a solution?

Comment: nope. I still see it on reboots, but there aren't any other issues.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me.
Updating docker (after re-enabling the repo in /etc/apt/sources.list) fixed the issue.

Comment: It would probably help to mention which repo you re-enabled, and how you did it (presumably removed # that was commenting out lines in sources.list?), and also how you updated docker (eg `sudo apt update docker.io`?). Without that detail this answer might be considered low-quality and deleted.